# How to use Java Timer to handle multiple repeating tasks?

Tags: java, timer

I want my java application first run repeat task A and then B then C with java Timer class.

plz help.

Comment: It will be better to use a library that handles job scheduling like [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Can you clarify your problem a bit?

Comment: i just want my application check database with a class then send mail with another class and i want this repeatedly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this approach. Extend it with proper exception handling to ensure that the next task is always scheduled.

```
static final Timer t = new Timer();
static final long delay = 1000;
public static void main(String[] args) {
  t.schedule(new A(), delay);
}
static class A extends TimerTask { public void run() {
    // do stuff;
    t.schedule(new B(), delay);
} }
static class B extends TimerTask { public void run() {
    // do stuff;
    t.schedule(new C(), delay);
} }
static class C extends TimerTask { public void run() {
    // do stuff;
    t.schedule(new A(), delay);
} }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor** is a better choice.
It's more accurate and better exception handling, if you are using JDK1.5+.